# Using GestureOverlayView or something similar inside of an Android Widget

Tags: android, widget, gesture

**Is it possible to create a widget that holds a GestureOverlayView?**

My goal is to create a widget that has 4 buttons stacks on top of eachother, to the left of a gesture pad. In my activities and fragments I am currently using a GestureOverlayView which allows me to read gestures, and match them to a library of saved gesture patterns, to determine a specific action.

In this next phase of the project I would like to replicate my gesture pane I have in my fragments and activities onto a widget that is placed on the Android homescreen.

I read an article that said FrameLayouts were allowed in Android, seeing as how GestureOverlayView extends from framelayout, my idealistic self figured this was possible.

So far I have gotten a widget with the same images and layouts I wish to use, and it displays without functionality just fine. The layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_app"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:background="@drawable/draw_pad_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/call" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/text" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/app" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/contact" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".03"
        android:background="@drawable/button_divider"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".85" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSeparateLayer_app"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip" 
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_centerVertical="true" /> <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="30dip" android:src="@drawable/call" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:scaleType="centerInside" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /> 
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"> <ImageView android:layout_height="30dip" 
                android:src="@drawable/text" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:scaleType="centerInside" 
                android:layout_marginTop="30dip" /> </LinearLayout> -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llOpenDSR"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/draw_pad_background"
                android:gravity="center" >
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If I add the gesture view it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_app"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:background="@drawable/draw_pad_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/call" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/text" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/app" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/contact" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".03"
        android:background="@drawable/button_divider"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".85" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSeparateLayer_app"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip" 
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_centerVertical="true" /> <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="30dip" android:src="@drawable/call" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:scaleType="centerInside" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /> 
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"> <ImageView android:layout_height="30dip" 
                android:src="@drawable/text" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:scaleType="centerInside" 
                android:layout_marginTop="30dip" /> </LinearLayout> -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llOpenDSR"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/draw_pad_background"
                android:gravity="center" >
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
            android:id="@+id/appGestures"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="false"
            android:fadeOffset="400"
            android:gestureColor="@color/default_gesture_color"
            android:gestureStrokeAngleThreshold="0.1"
            android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="80"
            android:gestureStrokeSquarenessThreshold="0.1"
            android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:uncertainGestureColor="@color/default_gesture_color_uncertain" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_notification"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I add this widget to my homescreen I get "Problem loading widget"

I then found this part of the documentation:

"While widgets could be understood as "mini apps", there are certain limitations that are important to understand before you start to embark on designing your widget:

Gestures

Because widgets live on the home screen, they have to co-exist with the navigation that is established there. This limits the gesture support that is available in a widget compared to a full-screen app. While apps for example may support a view pager that allows the user to navigate between screens laterally, that gesture is already taken on the home screen for the purpose of navigating between home panels.

The only gestures available for widgets are:

Touch
Vertical swipe"

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html

So does this mean I cannot use this view?